# How to use Count with Max function and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this query below to get a list of stale accounts but I wanted to try and get a count of the number of rows returned instead of a full listing  but am stuck & looking for help.

```
SELECT customer_name, MAX(order_date) AS last_Sale_Date
FROM sales_history
GROUP BY customer_name
HAVING max(order_date) <= '01/01/2017 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM sales_history
GROUP BY customer_name
HAVING max(order_date) <='01/01/2017 23:59:59';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b3629bcb2c752c85df843a8d982aaf51)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT customer_name, MAX(order_date) AS last_Sale_Date
      FROM sales_history
      GROUP BY customer_name
      HAVING max(order_date) < '2018-01-02'
     ) sh
```

Notice that I changed the date format in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this up there as an alternative and likely the way I would have written it:

```
select count(*)
from (select customer_name, max(order_Date) LastOrder
      from sales_history
      group by customer_name) LastOrders --Everyones last order
where LastOrder < '2018-01-02'
```

Results in a count of customers that haven't ordered since 1/2/2018.